# MVVMLight Toolkit Data Binding Technique

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, databinding

I'm simulating my real-world application by using a really simple demo app here, but it has the same concept. **The question is `MVVM Light Toolkit` specific, as the purpose of my project is to learn the workings of the toolkit.**

Let's say I have a `Main` form, inside which I have a `UserControl`. The `Main` has a stand-alone `TextBox`, and the user control itself contains a single `TextBox`. It would look something like this:

[image]

The goal is this: if the user types on the `Main` form `TextBox`, I want to see the text displayed on the `UserControl`'s `TextBox`, and wise-versa, in real time. I'm using the `TextChanged` event.

### UserControl XAML

When all the unnecessary clutter is removed my `UserControl` XAML looks like this:

```
<UserControl ...
             d:DesignHeight="80" d:DesignWidth="280">
    <Grid Background="LightSteelBlue">
        <TextBox Name="TxtDisplay" Background="PaleGreen" Grid.Row="1"
                 Width="250" Height="32"
                 TextChanged="TxtDisplay_TextChanged"
                 Text="{Binding Display, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### UserControl Code Behind

I have a `RoutedEvent` so I can bubble up the `TextChanged` event, and a `DependancyProperty` to send the content of the `TextBox` to the `Main`.

```
public partial class TextDisplay : UserControl
{
    public TextDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler RoutedTextChanged;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Display", typeof(string), typeof(TextDisplay));
    public string Display
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DisplayProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private void TxtDisplay_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Display = TxtDisplay.Text;
        RoutedTextChanged?.Invoke(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
    }
}
```

### Main Window XAML

`DataContext` is bound to the `MainViewModel`.

```
<Window ...
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Name="TxtInput" Width="200" Height="32"
                 Text="{Binding MainDisplay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MainDisplayTextChangedCommand}"                                                       
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TxtInput, Path=Text}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>

        <uc:TextDisplay Grid.Row="1" Width="300" Height="80"
                        Display="{Binding UCDisplayText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="RoutedTextChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UCDisplayTextChangedCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </uc:TextDisplay>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### MainViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public const string MainDisplayPropertyName = "MainDisplay";

    private string _mainDisplay = string.Empty;

    public string MainDisplay
    {
        get { return _mainDisplay; }
        set
        {
            if (_mainDisplay == value) { return; }
            _mainDisplay = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MainDisplay);
        }
    }

    public const string UCDisplayTextPropertyName = "UCDisplayText";

    private string _ucDisplayText = string.Empty;

    public string UCDisplayText
    {
        get { return _ucDisplayText; }
        set
        {
            if (_ucDisplayText == value) { return; }
            _ucDisplayText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => UCDisplayText);
        }
    }

    public MainDisplayTextChanged MainDisplayTextChangedCommand { get; private set; }
    public UCDisplayTextChanged UCDisplayTextChangedCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        MainDisplayTextChangedCommand = new MainDisplayTextChanged(this);
        UCDisplayTextChangedCommand = new UCDisplayTextChanged(this);
    }

    public void MainTextChanged()
    {
        UCDisplayText = MainDisplay;
    }

    public void UCTextChanged()
    {
        MainDisplay = UCDisplayText;
    }
}
```

### TextChanged Commands

The two `TextChanged` command classes derive from `ICommand` and is designed according to the pattern shown in the [`Official MVVM Toolkit Tutorial` on PluralSight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/mvvm-light-toolkit-fundamentals).

```
public class MainDisplayTextChanged : ICommand
{
    protected readonly MainViewModel _owner;

    public MainDisplayTextChanged(MainViewModel owner)
    {
        _owner = owner;

        _owner.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        };
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _owner.MainTextChanged();
    }
}

public class UCDisplayTextChanged : ICommand
{
    protected readonly MainViewModel _owner;

    public UCDisplayTextChanged(MainViewModel owner)
    {
        _owner = owner;

        _owner.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        };
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _owner.UCTextChanged();
    }
}
```

### QUESTIONS

Now this works, but I have this feeling that this might not quite be the right way to go about this. Particularly:

1. In `TextDisplay.xaml.cs` code's `TextChanged` event, if I don't do `Display = TxtDisplay.Text;` then the `DataBinding` alone doesn't update the `DependancyProperty` value. What am I doing wrong?
2. Can I avoid using `DependancyProperty` altogether? I know I can bind to a property of the `DataContext` and have changes reflected instantly, but I'm looking for a decoupled solution where the `UserControl can stand on it's own.
3. Is there a better design for the two `ICommand` derivative classes?
4. Any other comments/suggestions are also welcome.

### EDIT

Download the entire project [here](https://github.com/sachintha81/PublicDownloads/blob/master/MvvmLightDepProp.zip).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simplifications

What you want to do can be achieved with data-binding alone, you don't need all those commands.

1. Since both text-boxes should display the same content, we only need one string property in `MainViewModel`:

   ```
   private string _mainDisplay = "";
   public string MainDisplay
   {
       get => _mainDisplay;
       set { _mainDisplay = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
   }
   ```

   Note the lack of `() => MainDisplay`: because `RaisePropertyChanges` has an overload with a `[CallerMemberName]` parameter, the compiler will automatically insert the name of the property for us. Alternately, you can use `nameof(MainDisplay)`.
2. Your user-control should bind to this property, just like the text-box in `MainWindow.xaml`: `Display="{Binding MainDisplay, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`.
3. Now you can remove those command classes and anything related to them, including the `<i:Interaction.Trigger>` parts in `MainWindow.xaml` and the `MainTextChanged` and `UCTextChanged` methods in `MainViewModel`.
4. There's just one little detail left: we want changes in the user-control to be visible elsewhere immediately, but the textbox in `TextDisplay.xaml` doesn't have its `UpdateSourceTrigger` set to `PropertyChanged`. Fix that, and everything should work as expected without that `TextChanged` callback.

#### Answers

Regarding dependency properties, as far as I know WPF's data binding system requires either the source or target (or both) to be a dependency property, so if you don't want to set the `DataContext` of your user-control, then yes, you'll need to use dependency properties.

Which approach to take depends on the purpose of your user-control. If it's meant to display a certain item, then just set the `DataContext`, so an `ItemUserControl` always binds to a matching `ItemViewModel`. On the other hand, if a user-control is a reusable UI control (such as a fancy date-picker) then it makes sense to use dependency properties.

Regarding commands, the MVVM Light library comes with very two useful `RelayCommand` classes. In my experience you rarely need anything else. I mostly use commands for high-level actions (open project, save file, copy/paste, etc.), and they're usually tied to menu items or buttons via data-binding: `<Button Command="{Binding OpenFileCommand}" />`.

#### Other notes

- Properties that are only set once (in the constructor) don't need a `private set`, `{ get; }` is sufficient nowadays.
- Dependency properties can also be initialized with a `PropertyMetadata` object. This allows you to specify a default value and an on-changed callback. But you can also use a `FrameworkPropertyMedadata`, which offers additional settings. One useful setting in particular is `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault`.
- MVVM Light provides a `Set<T>` method that allows you to simplify your property setters to `set => Set(ref _mainDisplay, value);`. This will set the backing field and raise a `PropertyChangedEvent`.

Comment: That's very detailed, thanks! Regarding the Simplification, that's elegant, I will definitely use that. Re. `Dependency Properties` and `UserControl`, I'm mostly looking to develop a few reusable UserControls to use in my work, so it's crucial that they are decoupled. I will explore more about the `Dependency Property` option. Do you have any suggestions about the `RelayCommand`, a place to learn, a tutorial? There's a ton of them out there, so I welcome any personal favorite kinda suggestions.

Comment: Those relay command classes are quite easy to use. In my button example, the view-model would contain a `public ICommand OpenFileCommand { get; }` property, and initialize that in the constructor to `OpenFileCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenFile);`, where `OpenFile` is a method in your view-model class. Pressing the button will now invoke the `OpenFile` method.

Comment: Also note that commands can be 'disabled', which also disables any button or menu item that binds to them. That's what the `RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)` constructor and the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method are for.

Comment: WOW that's neat. Thanks, you've been really helpful, wish I could upvote more than once.